# Why am I not getting any results with my Selenium script using rotating proxies?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to scrape, Noob here, am not getting any results with this script, the script executes well but not sure why its not scrapping, i just picked these proxies from a free source am guessing if that could be a problem. Expecting some suggestions from experts here.

```
#This with rotating proxies, headless browser and 
import time
import random
import urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re

# Rest of the code...

# Set up Selenium options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

proxies = [
    '95.165.163.188:60103',
    '123.202.159.108:80',
    '27.147.174.107:8080',
    '202.180.20.10:55443',
    '161.35.211.124:80',
    '137.184.218.6:83',
    '102.0.2.246:32650',
    '190.57.245.250:8080',
    # Add more proxies as needed
]

# Set up the Chrome driver with Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

# Rest of the code...


def extract_emails(text):
    # Regular expression pattern to match email addresses
    pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
    emails = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return emails

def decode_email(email):
    # Decode special characters in email address
    decoded_email = urllib.parse.unquote(email)
    
    # Remove prefix "Email-"
    if decoded_email.startswith('Email-'):
        decoded_email = decoded_email[6:]
    
    return decoded_email

def scrape_google_search_results(search_term, driver):
    all_emails = []
    page_number = 0

    while page_number < 40:  # Maximum of 40 pages
        # Construct the URL for the search term and current page number
        url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}&start={page_number * 10}'
        
        # Set a random proxy from the list
        proxy = random.choice(proxies)
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
            'httpProxy': proxy,
            'ftpProxy': proxy,
            'sslProxy': proxy,
            'noProxy': None,
            'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
        }
        
        # Open the URL in the driver
        driver.get(url)
        
        # Wait for some time before scraping the page
        time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))  # Adjust the delay as needed
        
        # Get the page source
        page_source = driver.page_source
        
        # Extract email addresses from the search results page
        email_addresses = extract_emails(page_source)
        all_emails.extend(email_addresses)

        # Check if there are more search results
        if 'Next' not in page_source:
            break
        
        # Increment the page number
        page_number += 1
        
        # Wait for some time before scraping the next page
        time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))  # Adjust the delay as needed

    return all_emails

def save_emails_to_text(emails, filename):
    # Remove duplicate emails
    unique_emails = list(set(emails))
    
    if unique_emails:
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            for email in unique_emails:
                file.write(email + '\n')
        print(f'File "{filename}" saved.')
    else:
        print(f'No emails found for the search term.')

# Set up Selenium options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

# Define the list of proxies


# Set up the Chrome driver with Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Read city names from the file "indian_cities.txt"
with open("indian_cities.txt", 'r') as file:
    indian_cities = [city.strip() for city in file.read().split(',')]

# Read interests from the file "interests.txt"
with open("interests.txt", 'r') as file:
    interests = [interest.strip() for interest in file.read().split(',')]

for interest in interests:
    for city in indian_cities:
        # Set the search term
        #search_term = f'{city} {interest} "@gmail.com" site:instagram.com'
        search_term = f'new york health "@gmail.com" site:instagram.com'
        
        # Scrape Google search results for emails
        emails = scrape_google_search_results(search_term, driver)
        
        # Extract the first two words from the search term
        first_two_words = ' '.join(search_term.split()[:2])
        
        # Decode and filter the emails
        clean_emails = [decode_email(email) for email in emails if '@' in email and '%' not in email]
        
        # Generate the text file name
        filename = f'{first_two_words.replace("@gmail.com", "").replace(" ", "_")}.txt'
        
        # Save the clean emails to a text file if there are any
        save_emails_to_text(clean_emails, filename)

# Quit the driver and close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I tried adding proxies and everything works fine.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).